# AngularJs ng-repeat filtering by a deeper tier of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my data for appointments I have months, weeks, days, timeslots

In a listing view it is unimportant to show "weeks" (but it is important for other reports)

for "days" I can filter out days with no appointments as:

```
<div ng-repeat="month in appointments.months: | filter:{????:''}">
  <div>{{month.name}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="week in month.weeks"> <!--Not displaying anything for weeks-->
        <div ng-repeat="day in weeks.days | filter:{timeslots:''}">
    ....</div></div></div>
```

filter:{timeslots:''} has the desired effect of suppressing days without appointments.

I would also like to suppress months without appointments from the display. 
I have tried variations on **|filter:{weeks.days.timeslots:''}** with no success.

Is there a direct (built in) way to do a deep filter on values in angularjs or will I have to build a custom filter for this?

Comment: would you like to provide the appointments dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes there is a way exists!!!**

> A special property name `$` can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its nested object properties.
>   The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !. For example {name: "!M"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name not containing "M".

Here is the [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) explained.

Comment: you put me on the right track here... because I'm looking for a "not null" value to a particular property I had to nest this a little.

`|filter:{$:{timeslot:''}}` 
which would read as _include only objects with a timeslot property which has a value (or is not null)_